# Is it possible to call a static Java Class Method as defaultValueComputed?

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I like to fill a not nullable string in a liquibase schema generation (for postgres DB) with a value generated by an own class method.

Can't I use `defaultValueComputed` to call a static method of a class? e.g.

```
        <column name="downloadkey" type="VARCHAR(40)" defaultValueComputed="ch.util.HashUtil.randomSha1()">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
```

And the Java Class:

```
package ch.util;


public class HashUtil {
    public static String randomSha1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I try this, an exception is raised:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set ...
    Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: improper qualified name (too many dotted names): ch.util.hashutil.randomsha1 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE ....]
```

Comment: SHA is a hash algorithm that needs an input, a default value does not make sense

Comment: SHA-1 of an UUID is generated. It DOES make sense. If you disagree, please see `reandomSha1` as random string generator with 40 chars. But please focus on the real question.